# 2015 VW Passat TSI keyless start doesn't work. Is there a way to reprogram / reset the key myself?

Tags: starting, vw, passat, keyless-entry

I have changed the remote battery (brand new Sony CR2032, my meter shows a voltage of 3.2V on the battery, so I know it has full charge). The door lock/unlock, and trunk unlock buttons WORK on the remote. What doesn't work is the keyless door unlock/lock (by placing the hand on handle) and the keyless start. Pressing the engine start button says "key not in range" message. The yellow lock button is displayed in the dash.

If I touch the key on the steering wheel, and then press the start button, the engine starts.

What could be wrong here? Is there a way to fix this myself. I have another key which works correctly.